Apply Blog Home layout to Pages
In WordPress 6.7.1, I have customized my Blog Home template with the block editor in the Twenty Twenty-Four theme. It has a layout with two columns and many custom paddings, colors, fonts, and so on. My Pages template is virtually untouched.
Is there a way to apply all the changes I made to Blog Home in Pages?

Do you mean to existing pages? I blog home an Archive page?

I have a page called "Bio" with an artist biography and another page called "Gallery" with a photo gallery.
